# Analog of OUTER APPLY in other RDBMS (not SQL Server)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I'm using SQL Server at work, and I have some nice tricks with OUTER APPLY clause which helps me do not repeat code. For example, if I have a table like this:

```
create table Transactions
(
    ID bigint identity(1, 1) primary key, [Date] datetime, Amount decimal(29, 2), Amount2 decimal(29, 2)
)

insert into Transactions ([Date], Amount, Amount2)
select getdate(), 100.00, null union all
select getdate(), 25.00, 75.00
```

and I want to select data from it such as I will have row for each not null amount, I can do query like this:

```
select
  T.ID,
  T.[Date],
  OA.Amount
from Transactions as T
  outer apply (
      select T.Amount as Amount union all
      select T.Amount2 as Amount
  ) as OA
where OA.Amount is not null
```

instead of using `union`:

```
select
  T.ID,
  T.[Date],
  T.Amount
from Transactions as T
where T.Amount is not null

union all

select
  T.ID,
  T.[Date],
  T.Amount2 as Amount
from Transactions as T
where T.Amount2 is not null
```

So I wonder - are other RDBMS have such a possibility?

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e1f0/5)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3 will have `LATERAL` which is the ANSI equivalent of SQL Server's `outer apply`

Comment: Thank you, so there is ANSI equivalent :)

Comment: Some examples are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle a lateral join is a cartesian join with a result set that is dependent upon the values of the row. No new keyword has been introduced yet ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59f00/2)):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE number_nt AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  2  /

Type created
SQL> SELECT t.id, t.dt, u.column_value amount
  2    FROM Transactions t
  3   CROSS JOIN TABLE(number_nt(t.amount, t.amount2)) u;

        ID DT                AMOUNT
---------- ----------- ------------
         1 05/06/2013           100
         1 05/06/2013  
         2 05/06/2013            25
         2 05/06/2013            75
```

Oracle appears to use the `LATERAL` keyword [internally](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/ansi-outer/) though.

Comment: The standard `LATERAL` join is no necessarily a `CROSS JOIN`. See some examples here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this link lists three uses for lateral join: standard join, cross join and external cross join, all of which are can be rewritten as a cartesian product with a dependent result set.

Comment: Did you see the `... LEFT JOIN LATERAL ...`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You can do an [external cross join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59f00/13) =) Though I aggre the LATERAL operator is more convenient and elegant, and I have the feeling that it will be introduced in future versions of Oracle, since apparently it is used internally.