# refer to value of unnest (or other srf) in WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

While I'm trying to find good answer on my question [Analog of OUTER APPLY in other RDBMS (not SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935160/analog-of-outer-apply-in-other-rdbms-not-sql-server) I've found pretty nice PostgreSQL solution:

```
create table Transactions
(
    ID int, Date timestamp, Amount decimal(29, 2), Amount2 decimal(29, 2)
);

insert into Transactions (ID, Date, Amount, Amount2)
select 1, current_timestamp, 100.00, null union all
select 2, current_timestamp, 25.00, 75.00;

select
    T.ID,
    T.Date,
    unnest(array[T.Amount, T.Amount2]) as Amount
from Transactions as T
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/490f7/1)

the point is to turn some columns into rows with most readable and elegant code I could get. But I don't want to see null columns as rows. Is there any way I could use value from unnest in WHERE clause of the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery and `where` to filter out the `NULL` values:

```
select id, date, Amount
from (select t.*, unnest(array[T.Amount, T.Amount2]) as Amount
      from Transactions as T
     ) t
where Amount is not null;
```

Postgres doesn't allow the `unnest` direction in the `where` clause.

EDIT:

`Unnest` uses the length of the array to determine the number of rows.  You can do this with standard SQL and no subquery, but you will probably find it messier:

```
      select T.ID, T.Date,
             (case when n = 1 then T.Amount
                   when n = 2 then T.Amount2
              end) as Amount
      from Transactions T cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
      where (case when n = 1 then T.Amount
                  when n = 2 then T.Amount2
             end) is not null;
```

Comment: I know I could do that or CTE, but it's not very elegant, I thought that there's a way...

Comment: The first suggestion might look less messy if you subselected only the `unnest`.